# how to make "argv detection function" simpler?

Tags: php

```php
function _detect_argv(){
    if(_cmd()){
        $arg1=isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])?$_SERVER['argv'][1]:'';
        $arg2=isset($_SERVER['argv'][2])?$_SERVER['argv'][3]:'';
        $arg3=isset($_SERVER['argv'][3])?$_SERVER['argv'][3]:'';
        $arg4=isset($_SERVER['argv'][4])?$_SERVER['argv'][4]:'';
        $arg5=isset($_SERVER['argv'][5])?$_SERVER['argv'][5]:'';
        if(!empty($arg1)&&!empty($arg2)&&!empty($arg3)&&!empty($arg4)&&!empty($arg5)){
            $arg1($arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5);
        }elseif(!empty($arg1)&&!empty($arg2)&&!empty($arg3)&&!empty($arg4)){
            $arg1($arg2,$arg3,$arg4);
        }elseif(!empty($arg1)&&!empty($arg2)&&!empty($arg3)){
            $arg1($arg2,$arg3);
        }elseif(!empty($arg1)&&!empty($arg2)){
            $arg1($arg2);
        }elseif(!empty($arg1)){
            $arg1();
        }
        system('exit');die;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of arguments, it looks like this code is not clean, how to simplify this function?

Comment: Please post your question in code review instead : [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) . For details, see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There is also `$argc`, which is the number of arguments.. no need to test them individually

Comment: after drink 2 glasses coffee :)..
i'm finally managed to make it simpler, just using "for($i=2;"..

Comment: Are you aware that you can only have gaps in argument array if you have prior code that removes elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['argv'] = [ 'strlen' ];

// Remove empty values in $_SERVER['argv'].
// Since all entries in _SERVER are strings it removes entries being '' and '0'.
$args = array_filter($_SERVER['argv']);

// Alternatively if for example '0' should not be removed
$args = array_filter($_SERVER['argv'], fn($item) => $item !== '');
// Or if for example the value should be trimmed first
$args = array_filter($_SERVER['argv'], fn($item) => trim($item) !== '');

// Remove the first element
$func = array_shift($args);

if (function_exists($func)) {
    $func(...$args);
} else {
    die('First argument is not a function');
}
```